# How do I create a score counter in Android Studio?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I'm a complete newbie to Android Studio and have basic experience in Java. I tried to create an android app where the user has to input a number, once the button is clicked a random number is generated from 0-6, if the input number and the generated number is the same then the user gains 1 point. I've tried to implement a score counter but after 1 correct guess the score stays at 1 and never increases any further.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
String matchingnumbers = "Congratulations!";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}

public void on_button_click(View view) {
    TextView numberW = this.findViewById(R.id.textView);
    EditText tvW = this.findViewById(R.id.editText);
    TextView scoreW =this.findViewById(R.id.textView3);
    Random r = new Random();
    int dicenumber = r.nextInt(6);
    numberW.setText(Integer.toString(dicenumber));

    try {
        int number = Integer.parseInt(numberW.getText().toString());
        int tv = Integer.parseInt(tvW.getText().toString());
            if(number==tv){
                int score = 0;
                score++;
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), matchingnumbers, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                scoreW.setText("Your score is = " + score);
        }

    }
    catch (Exception ex) {
        Log.e("Button Errors", ex.toString());
    }
}
}
```

Comment: on_button_click it being called ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't declare `score` in the method, because it does not remain. Declare it in the class instead:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
String matchingnumbers = "Congratulations!"; 
//here
int score = 0;
// ...
}
```

Comment: It works now, but I would like to know why it doesn't remain in the method?

Comment: Because it's a local variable if you declare in the method, and the local variables will not remain outside the method, because declaring a variable in the method means "I only want to use that variable in the method".

Comment: See [local variables in java](https://www.dummies.com/programming/java/local-variables-in-java/).

Answer (score 0):

The Code you have written is this ....

```
if(number==tv)
   {
       int score = 0;
       score++;
       Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), matchingnumbers, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
       scoreW.setText("Your score is = " + score);
   }
```

Observe the statements in **if** condition. Inside the **if** you are creating score variable so each time the user gets the correct answer the score variable will be created and its incremented so you will get always 1 as output even you get the same combination so many times

So, understand the **scope** of that variable.